# Hibernate Configuration: Jar files?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jar

im noobie here but i have been finding the fix of my problem here i dont see it... Im new with hibernate and im using my free time to learn this.

```
package negocio;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.Service;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;


import integracion.HibernateUtil;
import integracion.dao.BodegaDAOImpl;
import integracion.dao.VinoDAO;
import integracion.dao.VinoDAOImpl;
import integracion.entidades.Bodega;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SessionFactory sessionFactory;


        Configuration configuration  = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();

        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry
        = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        //The problem is here
        **sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);**

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        BodegaDAOImpl bodegaDao = new BodegaDAOImpl<>();
        bodegaDao.get(1);


    }

}
```

This is the list of the jar added[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vy9Fn.png)

And this is the mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vinoteca</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>


    <mapping class="integracion.entidades.Vino"/>
    <mapping class="integracion.entidades.Bodega"/>
    <mapping class="integracion.entidades.Denominacion"/>

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>




dic 15, 2016 12:37:51 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.9.Final}
dic 15, 2016 12:37:51 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
dic 15, 2016 12:37:51 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
dic 15, 2016 12:37:51 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
dic 15, 2016 12:37:51 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
dic 15, 2016 12:37:51 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vinoteca]
dic 15, 2016 12:37:51 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
dic 15, 2016 12:37:51 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
dic 15, 2016 12:37:51 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Thu Dec 15 00:37:51 CET 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
dic 15, 2016 12:37:51 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/NamedStoredProcedureQuery
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindDefaults(AnnotationBinder.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.prepare(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
    at negocio.Main.main(Main.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more
```

So.. this is the problem. I was seeing that the problem when eclipse says `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery`

was because the jar (javax.persistence.jar or hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0...jar) was not added, but i added them and i dont resolve this.

anyone could say me why is working bad? Thanks!
PD:Sorry for my english, im not Native english speaker =)

Comment: Clearly not the JPA API, so kindly do not tag as that

Answer (score 0):

Use a build system like maven or gradle to build your project, and add a dependency on hibernate. That will almost certainly solve all of your basic dependency-related classpath problems.

Comment: is it necessary work with maven in this moment? ive never used maven and i prefer to work in first step with hibernate (developing easy examples) and after that learn maven and work with it...

Comment: @Egocéntrico Manually building your classpath is something like coding in assembly when you have a C compiler available: Unless you really know what you're doing, you're probably doing it wrong. Basic maven or gradle is easy to use and you'll find plenty of examples online. You can even use maven to easily find the jars you need, for example using `mvn dependency:tree`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the required jar files into the classpath.